# Поиск по дереву не находит нужный элемент по его id

Tags: javascript, поиск, дерево

День добрый.

Прошу подсказать, где ошибка в `Tree.searchById()`. Метод находит элемент только, если он с индексом `0` (`TreeEl.children[0]`).

В остальных случая `undefined`.

```
class Id {
    static lastId = 0;

    static getId() {
        this.lastId++;
        return this.lastId - 1;
    }
}
class TreeEl {
    constructor() {
        this.id = Id.getId();
        this.parentId = undefined;
        this.name = "Node" + this.id;
        this.children = [];
    }
}
class Root extends TreeEl {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.name = "Root";
    }
}
class Node extends TreeEl {
    constructor(parentId) {
        super();
        this.parentId = parentId;
    }
}
class Tree {
    constructor() {
        this.data = [];
        this.data.push(new Root());
    }

    addNode(parentId) {

        let parent = this.searchById(parentId);
        if (parent) {
            parent.children.push(new Node(parentId));
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    delNode(id) {

    }

    searchById(id, arr = this.data) {

        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i].id == id) {
                return arr[i];
            }else {
                return this.searchById(id, arr[i].children);
            }
        }

    }
}


let tree = new Tree();
tree.addNode(0);//1
tree.addNode(0);//2
tree.addNode(0);//3
tree.addNode(0);//4
tree.addNode(0);//5
console.log(tree);
console.log(tree.searchById(2));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в `searchById` когда не выполняется условие `arr[i].id == id`, то в `else` сразу возвращается `this.searchById(id, arr[i].children)`.

Т.е, метод проверяет только `0` элемент в массиве, потом `0` элемент у потомка и так рекурсивно.

Нужно переписать так:

```
searchById(id, arr = this.data) {

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].id === id) {
            return arr[i];
        }
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        const el =  this.searchById(id, arr[i].children);
        if(el)
            return el;
    }
}
```

**P.S.**

1. Не используйте нестрогое сравнение `==`. Если вы уверены в типе, то лучше всегда использовать `===`.
2. Странный синтаксис. Вроде как поля нужно в конструкторе объявлять.

   ```
   class Id {
       static lastId = 0;

       static getId() {
           this.lastId++;
           return this.lastId - 1;
       }
   }
   ```

   Типо такого:

   ```
   class Id {
       static getId() {
           if (!this.lastId)
               this.lastId = 0;
           this.lastId++;

           return this.lastId - 1;
       }
   }
   ```